# How to aim at the next <ul> list item in an <ul> with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I want to dynamically show the next `<ul>` list item on a mouseenter over the first `<li>` item.
The first part of the script works as expected, the animation of the next list item in the first list.
However I have no function on showing the next `<ul>`. Any tips would be of great help.

You can see the so far working script here: http://liebdich.biz/test/test.php.

Here is the code

```
<head>
<style>
.masteringtext {
height:262px;
width:355px;
background:grey; 
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.masteringtext ul {
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
cursor:pointer;
}

.masteringtext ul li {
display:inline-block;
background:#c3c3c3;
border:solid 1px black;
border-radius:5px;
padding:1px;
}

.overlay {
margin-left:-30px;
}

.profile {
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:0;
top:25px;
display:none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="masteringtext">
<ul>
<li>Equipment</li>
    <li class="overlay">Kosten</li>
    <li class="overlay">Referenzen
        <ul class="profile">
            <li>Dies ist ein Test<br> um darzustellen was schon lange nötig war</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="overlay">Ablauf einer Bestellung</li>
    <li class="overlay">Tips für Mixe</li>
    <li class="overlay">Faq</li>
</ul>


</body>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var overlay = $('li');


overlay.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).next().animate({'margin-left':0},400, function() {
        $(this).next('ul').show();
    });
});

overlay.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).next().animate({'margin-left':-30});
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Try using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of .next().

Comment: Thanks, tried, still not working.

Comment: I copied your code and made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNWeZ/), it works there.

Comment: @RichardA Thanks, that's awesome. Funny though, because I wanted to do a fiddle too for this question and it did not work at all. ;)

Comment: Probably because you had a few settings wrong. Remember that you have to set your jQuery version and the right wrap. (I set mine in *No Wrap - in <body>* as you can see.)

Comment: @RichardA Look at your fiddle, it shows the list item on mouseenter of the previous list item. In Arun's fiddle it is working though!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to move the next `li` to further right and then show the `ul` which is inside the current `li`

```
overlay.mouseenter(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    $li.next().stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left':0},400, function() {
        $li.find('ul').show();
    });
});

overlay.mouseleave(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    $li.next().stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left':-30}, function() {
        $li.find('ul').hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2yXcW)

Comment: Thanks Arun, that's awesome. But look at my comments below, I do not know where your functionality comes from in comparison to mine. Or have a look at Richard's fiddle. I just copied your code, weird, it works. The only difference is the setting of the variable `$li`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<ul>` in question is not a *sibling*, but rather a *child* of the `<li>`

Replacing

```
$(this).next('ul').show();
```

with

```
$(this).find('ul').show();
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but now the new list item is shown on mouseenter over the "previous" list item of where the new `<ul>`is?!?

Comment: @dollarvar That seems to be a CSS issue, not a jQuery issue.

Comment: I meant Arun's fiddle.

Comment: @dollarvar He's hiding it onmouseleave, I didn't. Arun also saves the reference to the `li` element before the animation, I didn't. So disregard my Fiddle since Arun's works a bit better. Use that one as an example.

Comment: @RichardA The thing is, I cannot copy the functionality of Arun's fiddle to my script. It is showing the `ul` of "Referenzen" when mouse entering on "Kosten". That's weird. Can you see it?

Comment: @dollarvar Yeah, I noticed it aswell. That's because when using a callback function in the animate function `$(this)` will be a reference to the object(s) being called in that function instead of the `li` element you want. That's why he saves that reference. I hope I wasn't too unclear on this, if I was, we'll open a chatroom if you'd like.

Comment: @RichardA Ah, I see, because he defines the variable outside the function it takes the `$this`from outside the function? Wait, but then `this`is not defined yet, hmmm, gotta think about that.

Comment: @dollarvar `this` is technically always defined, it's all scope dependant. `this` in `onmouseenter` will refer to the element or object you called it on. `this` in the callback function of `.animate()` will refer to the object `.animate()` is called on. But if anything else, `this` will refer to the window or document.